# Visualise the impact of the scoring model for a competition

Tags: visualization

I'm designing the scoring model of a competition. The competition will have N tasks. Each task can have 6 different outcomes corresponding to 6 different scores. The final score for each participant is the average score for all N tasks.

Is there a way to visualise the impact the scoring model has on the overall results for all the participants?

N.B. the scoring model is a mix of penalising and rewarding the solution to the considered task